# The difference between Present Subjunctive Conditional and Past Subjunctive Conditional?

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, present-tense

I am trying to understand what is the lexical difference between next sentences:

If I went to London, I would see the Thames

and

If I had gone to London, I would have seen the Thames

Comment: A simple internet research for "conditional sentences" would have yielded ample results for your question. What you're looking for is Second and Third Conditionals.

Comment: thanks for your advice but I am trying to translate it to my language and the translation is same for both 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I went to London, I would see the Thames.

can mean two things:

1 it describes a repeated past activity.

2 it describes a non-past irrealis. The speaker is not actually going to London.

and

> If I had gone to London, I would have seen the Thames.

This is  a past irrealis. The person did not,   in the past, actually go to London.

Answer (score -1):

Could you drop London, leave out even the river and compare only the sights? How could *I would see…* have the same translation as *I would have seen…*

(Who says the translation to your language is the same… and what is your language, please? It might make a big difference…)